# Verification of a Step in Derivation

Tags: probability

In order to troubleshoot a problem of validating the results of a mathematically derived expression, I divided the derivation into segments.  The following segment seems to be the source of error in validation. Please verify the soundness of this segment.

Assume that there are $m$ sources of balls. Each source can provide infinitely many balls of a size distinctly specific to that source. In a trial, a source is picked via a uniform distribution. The probability of picking a source in a trial is $p=1/m$. Then, the probability of not picking a specific source in a trial is $1-p$. I am seeking the expectation of "number of picking trials required for picking each type of ball at least once".

Some of the sources are deliberately selected to be excluded from the process of uniform picking of sources. Let event $e_{1}$ denote that $n$ sources are selected out of $m$ sources. There are $\binom{m}{n}$ possible cases of event $e_{1}$. Therefore, $P(e_{1})=1/\binom{m}{n}$.

Let event $e_{2}$ denote that the selected $n$ sources are excluded from the process of uniform picking in first $i$ trials. Event $e_{2}$ depends on event $e_{1}$. As the probability of a specific source not being picked in a trial is  $1-p$, the probability that $n$ specific (selected for exclusion) sources are not picked in single trial is $1-\binom{n}{1} \times p = 1-np$. Then for the first $i$ consecutive trials, the conditional probability $P(e_{2} \mid e_{1})=(1-np)^{i}$.

The probability that both events $e_{1}$ and $e_{2}$ occur, i.e. none of sources picked in first $i$ trials are from $n$ sources selected for exclusion, is $$P(e_{1} \;\mbox{and}\; e_{2})= P(e_{1})P(e_{2} \mid e_{1})=1/\binom{m}{n} \times (1-np)^{i}$$

The picking process is said to be converged when all the sources are picked. When convergence has not been achieved, at least one and at most $(m-1)$ sources remain to be picked. Therefore, the probability that convergence has not occurred till first $i$ trials is

$$P(\underset{n \in {1,2,...,m}} \cup (e_{1} \;\mbox{and}\; e_{2}))= \underset{n=1}{\overset{m}{\sum}} 1/\binom{m}{n} \times (1-np)^{i} $$

A better approach to derive the probability distribution and expectation of "required number of trials" is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). Problem solved.

Comment: The problem is a little unclear.  The event $e_1$ seems to refer to the selection of $n$ out of $m$ ball sources.  Then the event $e_2$ (conditioned on $e_1$) seems to refer to none of the $n$ previously selected sources being picked for any of the first $i$ trials.  Can you elaborate on the distinction between a selection and a picking?

Comment: Please let me know if there is any ambiguity.

Comment: Your conditional probability is odd. Can you edit the thread with a more detailed explanation of how you came up with that specific expression?

Comment: I really having difficulty to understand that paragraph about conditional probability, and it really sounds like the problem is there. From what I could get, shouldn't the conditional probability be a chain of products: $(1-np) (1-np)^2 (1-np)^3 ...$?